# Why message is being sent to everyone instead of one user in Django Channels?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am building a WebRTC videochat app. I have a function of holding the user on a line, which works great: I press a button, the signal goes to the server, the server sends it to the user using self.channel_layer.send(), the user gets alert() and puts on hold.
But when I want to unhold the user, the server sends a signal to everyone in the room, despite all the parameters are the same as in "hold" function.
Holding user:

```python
if action == 'onhold':  #holding user
            await self.channel_layer.send(
                list(usersChannels.keys())[list(usersChannels.values()).index(message['peer'])], #channel to hold
                {
                    'type': 'channel_message',
                    'action': 'onhold',
                    'room': 'room',
                    'message': {message['peer']: '1'},
                }
            )
            return
```

Unholding user:

```python
if action == 'unhold':  # unholding user
            await self.channel_layer.send(
                list(usersChannels.keys())[list(usersChannels.values()).index(message['peer'])], # channel to unhold
                {
                    'type': 'channel_message',
                    'action': 'unhold',
                    'room': 'room',
                    'message': {message['peer']: '1'},
                }
            )
            return
```

Full code here: https://pastebin.com/CicsUhy4

Comment: I did a chat application these days and the solution that I found was to open two ws connections, one specific for the user and the other to the chat room itself, when I need to send a message to a specific user I get his ID and sent to this group. Check `notify_participants` on https://github.com/Dosbodoke/Spin/blob/main/backend/chat/consumer.py to see the code example

Comment: In this case, I'm looping over each user that is a member of that chat and sending a private message to him, like a notification message!